# How can I find every \function or \symbol ever?

Tags: latex-misc

I want a list, or a way to create a list that contains every valid

```
\somecommand
```

entry.

Ideally I would be able to tell without having to test it, how many parameters it takes. Thus far, the largest list I have found is about 2500, however it is still missing plenty of commands and symbols.

Comment: Do you want to limit this to all packages on CTAN (of which there are thousands)? Or some smaller scope? https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/ has >14000 symbols.

Comment: Good question; my backstory is that I am creating a library that will interpret Latex into readable speech. This will be useful for the blind, and for audiobooks in general. 
The only limitation I could possibly put on this, is whatever is compatible with Wikipedia's `<math> </math>` tags. However, I don't mind doing the >14k if I can get enough useful metadata on the symbols that can help me streamline writing code for it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Additionally, I would like the greatest list possible, because this would benefit the community. What I am doing, is that I am dumping this list to a google spreadsheet with any metadata I can muster. If I make this public, this will be an extremely useful repository for the community at large.

Comment: Another decision concerns packages.  While a package may provide the user a handful of new macros, the *internal* macros in any given package can easily be hundreds to thousands.  Do you want those too?

Comment: Worst case; Yes, just to include them in my repository; they will probably be seperated. Best case; yes, especially if they have a lot of metadata. The dump of 2500 for example gave me unicode character equivalents; this is extremely useful, because it allows me to sort for duplicates. For example: /rightarrow and /to can effectively be targetted collectively.

Comment: To get all of the macros, you could write a program to go through every package on CTAN, download it, and analyse all of the macro definitions with `\def`, `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\providecommand`, `\declarecommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\RenewDocumentCommand`, `\ProvideDocumentCommand`, and `\DeclareDocumentCommand`. Oh, and all the environment definitions too...

Comment: I use the "Search->Find in Files.." feature of TexnicCenter to check all of the sty files I have loaded for names.  The downside it that it lists every usage as well as the definitions.  You should also download source2e.pdf and symbols.pdf from ctan.